# Is it possible to inherit from a template base class with virtual function overriding with template argument?

Tags: c++, constants

When I use `class Derived: public Base<int*>`, I thought the Base class template is a member function like `virtual void foo(const int* a) {}` because of explicit instantiation during compilation.
However, If I write like this, it never shows "Derived class".
What's happening?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void foo(const T a)
    {
        cout << "Base foo" << endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base<int*> // But " template<typename T> class Derived : public Base<T> {...} " works fine...
{
public:
    virtual void foo(const int* a)
    {
        cout << "Derived foo" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base<int*>* p = new Derived;
    p->foo(0);  // "Base foo"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for `const T`, `const` is qualified on `T` itself. Then given `T` is `int*`, the parameter type of `Base<T>::foo`, i.e. `const T` would be `int * const` (const pointer to non-const `int`), but not `const int *` (non-const pointer to const `int`).

You should change `Derived::foo` to

```
virtual void foo(int* const a)
{
    cout << "Derived foo" << endl;
}
```

Other issues: (1) don't forget to `delete` the pointer `p` at last; (2) `Base` should have a `virtual` destructor.

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BoS7r16OxaDAtH64)